# Is there any way to pass multiple arguments to function in Java?

Tags: java, arguments, messageformat

I have a function which currently only accepts two arguments - a string and a List for arguments.

This function goes ahead, gets a string from a language file. In this language file, I wanted to allow a possiblity to add arguments, which would be filled. Example: `"{1} has thanked {2}"`. The function then goes ahead, and using `MessageFormat.format` adds the arguments to the message.

I've gotten used to other languages (namely SourcePawn) which support the following syntax:
`print("%s has thanked %s", user1, user2)`
which replaces the `%s` tags with the arguments, and I wanted to replicate this in Java. Is there any way to do so?

Desired result would be to make the function work like this:
`fillInArguments("Hello {1}! You have {2} unread messages!", user.getName(), user.getUnreadMsgs())`

Comment: Look in to [String.format](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))  with syntax discription [Formatter syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use String.format like this :

```
String.format("Hello %s! You have %d unread messages!", user.getName(), user.getUnreadMsgs());
```

Symbol following "%" will depends of the type of the variable you want to add in the string. see table here https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-format

But if you directly have the parameters i guess you can also simply use concatenation like this :

```
"Hello " + user.getName() + "! You have " + user.getUnreadMsgs() + " unread messages!"
```

Comment: Nicely explained, thanks. The hard-coded paramaters were just a quick code I came up with to explain what I meant, but I'd definitely use the concatenation if I had them set up like that.